# Revolution Slider not working on some iPhones

Tags: css, wordpress

As the title says, Revolution slider will not work on some iPhones which is very very odd.

For example on an iPhone 11 it will not work but it will work on an iPhone 11 Pro Max.

By saying doesnt work I mean it doesnt show up! Just empty space.

I use browserstack to troubleshoop.

https://starmedicines.com.cy/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you tried adding https: to the front of the image urls e.g. in data-thumb="//starmedicines.com.cy/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/slide-2-50x100.jpg"

Comment: the whole slider doesnt load so this wasnt the issue, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem. So I use these code in htaccess file. And It's working fine in all iphone.

```
Header unset Content-Security-Policy
#Header add Content-Security-Policy "default-src * 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-dynamic' data: filesystem: about: blob: ws: wss:"
#Header unset X-Content-Security-Policy
Header add X-Content-Security-Policy "default-src * 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-dynamic' data: filesystem: about: blob: ws: wss:"
Header unset X-WebKit-CSP
Header add X-WebKit-CSP "default-src * 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-dynamic' data: filesystem: about: blob: ws: wss:"
```